# @ngrx/effects API request handling

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx, reactivex

I had a case where my login form was stopping working after a single failure login attempt, for making request I've been using effect, and that's how it was looking before changes:

```js
@Effect()
login$ = this.actions$.ofType<authActions.Login>(
  authActions.LOGIN,
).switchMap(
  ({ payload: data }) => this.client.login(data),
).map(
  ({ token }) => new authActions.LoginSuccess(token),
).catch(
  (error) => of(new authActions.LoginFailure(error)),
);
```

To be specific - when an user was trying to login after a failure attempt the `Login` action was dispatched correctly to the store, yet the effect was not launching.

I was desperately trying to fix that bug, then I've made a change that I thought was meaningless:

```js
@Effect()
login$ = this.actions$.ofType<authActions.Login>(
  authActions.LOGIN,
).switchMap(
  ({ payload: data }) => this.client.login(data).map(
    ({ token }) => new authActions.LoginSuccess(token),
  ).catch(
    (error) => of(new authActions.LoginFailure(error)),
  ),
);
```

But fortunately that (IMO) meaningless change fixed everything. Suddenly the effect was successfully launching after a failure login attempt. Could somebody explain me what happen?

Comment: https://medium.com/@P_Lessing/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9

Comment: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/blob/master/README.md#rxjs-no-unsafe-catch

Comment: thank you @cartant, can you post an answer that I could accept?

Comment: Sure. I can write one up a little later - on mobile ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an error is caught by the `catch` (or, in RxJS version 6, `catchError`) operator, the composed observable continues with a *different* observable.

That means that when an error occurs, your effect continues with the `of(new authActions.LoginFailure(error))` observable that's returned within the `catch`.

Continuing with that observable will see the `LoginFailure` action dispatched, but after that, the observable completes. That means the effect completes and its subscribers are then automatically unsubscribed. So the effect stops dispatching further actions.

This is discussed in more detail in Paul Lessing's article [Handling Errors in NgRx Effects](https://medium.com/city-pantry/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9) and there is a TSLint rule - [`rxjs-no-unsafe-catch`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules#rxjs-no-unsafe-catch) - to detect this particular problem in my [`rxjs-tslint-rules`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules) package.